# Assigning the name in a nested list to it's subcomponents

Tags: r, list, names

I have a nested list `current_output` that I would like to unlist and obtain the `expected` output. I would like to assign the name of the list in `current_output` to it's sub-components. For example, I would like to assign the name `A` to the three sub-components in `current_output`, and similarly for `B` and `C` to match those in the `expected.

```
A1 <- c(1:3)
A2 <- c(4:6)
A3 <- c(7:9)
B1 <- c(1:2)
B2 <- c(3:4)
B3 <- 1
C1 <- c(1:3)
C2 <- 1
C3 <- 1

l1 <- list(list(A1), list(A2), list(A3))
l2 <- list(list(B1),list(B2), list(1))
l3 <- list(list(C1), list(1), list(1))

current_output <- list(l1, l2, l3)
names(current_output) <- c("A", "B", "C")


expected <- list(A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3)
names(expected) <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 3))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to have unique key i.e. names for the list elements - loop over the nested list, `flatten`, then `invoke` by concatenating again, and change the names by removing the suffix digits from the names

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
out <- current_output %>% 
   map(flatten) %>%   
   invoke(c, .) %>%  
   setNames(str_remove(names(.), "\\d+"))
```

-testing

```
> all.equal(out, expected)
[1] TRUE
```

---

Or another option is `rrapply`

```
rrapply::rrapply(current_output, how = 'flatten') %>% 
    setNames(rep(names(current_output), lengths(current_output)))
```

---

Or using `base R`, `unlist` the list elements, convert each element to list element with `as.list` and then remove the digits from the names with `sub` and assign back the names

```
out <- as.list(unlist(current_output))
names(out) <- sub("\\d+$", "", names(out))
```

Comment: Is there a way to implement this in base R? Also when I try to run this it say that the function `str_remove` can't be found.

Comment: @JohnHuang Sorry, I used `library(stringr)` updated

Comment: @JohnHuang updated with `base R`

Comment: In the base version `unlist` will work recursively. Maybe use instead `unlist(unlist(current_output, FALSE, FALSE), FALSE)` and maybe use then better setNames like shown in rrapply: `unlist(unlist(current_output, FALSE, FALSE), FALSE) |> setNames(rep(names(current_output), lengths(current_output)))`

Answer (score 2):

Another base R approach that uses multiple `unlist()` steps.

```
setNames(
  unlist(current_output, recursive = F) %>% unlist(recursive = F), 
  rep(names(current_output), each = 3)
  )
```

#### Output

```
$A
[1] 1 2 3

$A
[1] 4 5 6

$A
[1] 7 8 9

$B
[1] 1 2

$B
[1] 3 4

$B
[1] 1

$C
[1] 1 2 3

$C
[1] 1

$C
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

current_output %>% imap(set_names) %>% flatten %>% flatten

#> $A
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $A
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> $A
#> [1] 7 8 9
#> 
#> $B
#> [1] 1 2
#> 
#> $B
#> [1] 3 4
#> 
#> $B
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $C
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $C
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $C
#> [1] 1
```

---

Or simply using a nested `for` loop in base R:

```r
expected <- list()

for (i in seq_along(current_output))
  for (j in seq_along(current_output[[i]]))
  { 
    expected <- c(expected, current_output[[i]][[j]])
    names(expected)[length(expected)] <- names(current_output)[i]
  }

expected
```